# “GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h file not found” when trying to build my project

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I get the error

```
GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h file not found
```

when I try to build the project. I just added the Google Plus framework into the project, and after that, I tried to import the framework in the `app delegate.m` file, but I’m just getting this error.

Comment: is GooglePlus framework added to Link binary with libraies?

Comment: in build setting add -ObjC in other linker flags

Comment: No, don't add `-ObjC` to build setting as it will have no effect at all.

Comment: Remove Google Plus framework and add it again .This error is occurring because of framework path changed in Header path.

Comment: You don't appear to be following the instructions from Google.  They say `#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>` in the header file and `#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>` in the implementation file.

Comment: i am testing the project ios quick start app from google. i download the project google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1. i run it on xcode but i am getting the error. even i removed framework and added again.still problem persists

Comment: Thanks for all of them. Its started working after i downloaded the another Framework SDK for IOS 6.0 from google developers site

Comment: Delete the unit testing from your project follow the below steps this will solve the issue.
select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. From the target delete the test from the left side of the project editor and press the Delete key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to remove current framework and bundle for Google plus and then download the latest one framework for Google plus from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1.zip & add them from project's Build_Settings>Build_Phases.

This way i have solved my problem, may be u too can get it.

Thanks
K.D

Answer (score 9):

Drag and Drop the **google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1** folder into `Framework` search path in `Build Settings`.

Its works fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, under "**Build Settings** > **Search Path** > **Framework Search Paths**" i had

```
$(inherited)          non-recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR)/My     non-recursive
Project/Frameworks    non-recursive
```

i think spaces are breaking the directory path
changing it to **`$(PROJECT_DIR)/"My Project"/Frameworks`** solved my problem..

Take note that `My Project` is my project name, `Frameworks` is where my *GooglePlus.bundle & .framework*, in case yours contains spaces, adding quotation marks corrects it.. for example: **`$(PROJECT_DIR)/"My Project"/"Google Frameworks".`**

Comment: You are right. My paths was outdated, so why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and what got it fixed was removing the spaces from the names of parent folder(s) of the framework. With spaces in the names of parent folder(s), Xcode will show multiple directories in "Framework Search Paths".

And sorry, I could not add it as a comment as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

One thing which I was missing adding 
[-ObjC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) in linker flag , but it did not removed the error. 
Then I removed `#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>` from .pch file and added into my `ViewController.h`. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had modified the path of `Build Settings->Search Paths->Framework Search Paths` to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/yourProject/3rdParty/"Google API"`.

Here, it's important to add the quoter mark. If you miss the mark, then Xcode will know as `$(PROJECT_DIR)/yourProject/3rdParty/"Google"` and API.

Answer (score 0):

Drug&Drop needed framework from Pods/Frameworks of your workspace to YourProject/Frameworks and select "Directory reference"