# lexical preprocessor issue GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus

1) I am having google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1.

2) I have added all frameworks in project's Build_Settings ->Build_Phases.

3) In my Build Settings i kept YES to Always search user paths.

4) Here are the snapshots of that [image]

[image]

5) After going through

[“GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h file not found” when trying to build my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931651/i-am-getting-googleplus-googleplus-h-file-not-found)

I did  Build->Clean and Restarted Xcode, after removing frameworks  and added once again but Xcode still giving GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this string to the `Build Settings->User Header Search Paths`

```
"${SRCROOT}/<--path-->/GooglePlus.framework/Headers"
```

The path "(SRCROOT)" is required if the google framework located in the sources folder.

E.g. for the my app this path looks like:

```
"${SRCROOT}/thirdparties/GooglePlus.framework/Headers"
```

Comment: Does not help for me...
Checking out an old project from a iOS developer who left the company. It still can't find GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h.