# ios error: GooglePlus/GooglePush.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, google-plus

My project has GooglePlus ios SDK-1.7.1

Today morning suddenly xcode has shown me this error while running my project. Due to the error I am Unable to build my project.

Restarted xcode & macbook few times, error gone.. It worked couple of times but later the error was persistent, Now it is not letting me to build my project.  I even tried cleaning the project `cmd+shift+k`, error disappears after my clean but shows again when I try to build the project.

[image]

I even tried the solutions that I found in below links but didn't work for me.

[lexical preprocessor issue GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563609/lexical-preprocessor-issue-googleplus-googleplus-h-not-found)

[“GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h file not found” when trying to build my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931651/googleplus-googleplus-h-file-not-found-when-trying-to-build-my-project)

One thing that I observed was there was no file called GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h in SDK framework when I searched in Finder.

Don't know what to do really.

Comment: Are you getting your GooglePlus SDK's via Cocoapods?  Do you have a Podfile?

Comment: Yes, I do have a pod file & I am downloading latest SDK from cocoapods.

Comment: Something I just noticed is that Google+ signin is now considered deprecated "and is likely to not function as expected".  There's a migration guide you can look at pointed to at this page:  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes Google+ signin got deprecated.