# Build iOS failed after changing back to the old xCode build servers

Tags: ios, xcode, build, codenameone

My app was successfully built with the old xCode and new 7.x xCode build servers in the past but it is always failed since CodenameOne changed the 7.x back to the current one. I tried it many times in last two weeks but it is still failed. Is there anyone facing same issue? The full error log is here https://thekingwilliamsolutions.wordpress.com/24-2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this relates to cn1libs you used. The specific failure is this:

> ## import "GoogleOpenSource.h"
>
> ```
>     ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

Which I'm guessing appears in one of your ios.* build hints and was added possibly by a cn1lib.

Comment: Shai, the exact error is

/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build8573786870773792451xxx/dist/PicturePuzzleZ-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.m:59:9: fatal error: 'GoogleOpenSource.h' file not found
#import "GoogleOpenSource.h"
        ^
1 error generated.

My app uses https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone plugin and I just downloaded and built this plugin again but it is still failed althought it used to successfully built in the past.

Comment: I think the CodenameOne_GLViewController.m file is generated and it imports the "GoogleOpenSource.h" but some how this file "not found" at server.

Comment: My app logon the Google+. Is there something regarding to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931651/i-am-getting-googleplus-googleplus-h-file-not-found

Comment: Google changed the way play services works and we had to update to keep up with them. It's possible that that ads API relies on the older version and broke as a result. To verify this remove the fullscreen ads cn1lib completely from the libs directory. Delete all the ios.* build hints you didn't add then do a "refresh libs". See if your project compiles properly. If so we just need to fix the full screen ads library to use the new semantics.

Comment: I tried several times and the https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone plugin with ios.add_libs=AdSupport.framework;SystemConfiguration.framework;CoreTelephony.framework and ios.objC=true build hints don't cause the build failed and the ios.gplus.clientId build hint actually causes the build failed with the error 'GoogleOpenSource.h' file not found

Comment: See this discussion https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1803

Comment: I have fixed this in SVN.  Will be on the build server soon.