# GoogleSignIn/GIDSignIn.h file not found

Tags: ios

I'm  new to Unity iOS development and wanted to include a Google Play services in my Unity app. I've downloaded the Unity package (installed Cocoa, made sure my Pod file is set up correctly etc).

However, when I build my app I get GoogleSignIn/GIDSignIn.h file not found.

So far I've tried:

> 1. Installing 'Google/SignIn' using Cocoa (throws an invalid name
>      exception that)
> 2. Linking the GoogleSignIn bundle through Xcode linked
>          libraries (makes no difference)
> 3. Upgrading all packages (same as in Google/Signin) Adding
>          $(inherited) to linker flags (no change)
> 4. checking FrameWork Search path,Header Search path

Pods file:

> platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'Unity-iPhone' do
>
> pod 'GooglePlayGames', '~> 5.0'
>
> end
>
> post_install do |installer|
>
> installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>
> target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>
> config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
>
> end end end

I go through this links:

- [“GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h file not found” when trying to build my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931651/googleplus-googleplus-h-file-not-found-when-trying-to-build-my-project)
- https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1526
- https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1460

Answer (score 0):

Change the pod file from below and again install the pod

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do

pod 'GooglePlayGames', '~> 5.0'

pod 'Google/SignIn'

end